# LibreOffice prevents SD card from being ejected

Tags: sd-card, libreoffice, eject

When I try to eject the SD card which is generally always in my Windows 7 netbook using either the context menu or the "Safely remove hardware and eject media" icon the computer tells me it can't because the device is in use.

Using certain tools I found that it's LibreOffice that has some kind of lock on the SD card. I can kill soffice.bin or soffice.exe and I can eject the card.

This happens without me ever actively using LibreOffice. It's just some kind of background task or daemon or service etc.

Is there an option or setting in LibreOffice to change this behaviour? Or is it a known bug in LibreOffice? Or what else should I do other than killing the task?

Comment: Is the "Quick Starter" activated? If so, just disable it (context menu option in systray, Menu `Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> Memory`). Does any of the paths defined point to the sd card? You can check this selecting Menu `Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> Paths`.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Quick Starter was on. Must've been default since I never used OO very much and don't recall changing that option. None of the paths are set to the SD card though. They're all set relative to C:

Comment: hmm, maybe there's still an entry in the "recent documents" list of libreoffice pointing to the sd. There are different tools to modify or clear the recent documents list, for example the [history manager extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/histmngr).

Comment: @tohuwawohu: I would consider holding locks to recent docs a bug but it doesn't do that since it contains entries for my unattached USB stick (H:) with no problems but none for my attached SD (D:)

Comment: indeed, sounds like a bug. I hope disabling the quick starter did solve the problem. If not, i'm at a loss...

Comment: I'll let you know next time I restart... (dozens of windows open)